# Change tag names and remove element for a certain value

Tags: xml, xslt

Am not able to traverse child element. In the below input XML, I have to take only element `<e>` and replace that with `<se>` and need to remove one element `<e>` if value equals to "DB1". Can someone help on this please? Am new to XSLT.

Input XML:

```
<a xmlns="http://examle.com/test/2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <b>
     <c name="RES" type="KSD">
     <d>
        <e>DB1</e>
        <e>DB2</e>
        <e>DB3</e>      
     </d>
    </c>
  </b>
  <error count="0" success="OK">
  </error>
</a>
```

The desired output XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Payload xmlns="http://example.com/test/2.0"xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <response>
        <allot>8</allot>            
        <size>200</size>
        <ses>
            <se>DB2</se>
            <se>DB3</se>
        </ses>          
    </response>
</Payload>
```

Comment: Please clarify, though: 1) The desired output seems to have hardly any connection to the input. So, do you actually want to essentially write a new document and insert a few values from the source document? 2) You point out that one `<e>` element gets removed - which one? Is it always the first one? Is it always the one with contents `DB1`? Any other rules for this? 3) Please explain what XSLT knowledge you're lacking in particular. SO is not about "write code for me", it's about "I am stuck at line XYZ; can you explain how to resolve error ABC that I'm getting?".

Answer (score 0):

The solution that seems to me to be closest to your needs (quite ambiguous) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rename -->
    <xsl:template match="a">
      <Payload>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </Payload>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rename and add some new elements -->
    <xsl:template match="b">
      <response>
        <allot>8</allot>            
        <size>200</size>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </response>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- don't output this node but only its children -->
    <xsl:template match="c">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rename -->
    <xsl:template match="d">
      <ses>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </ses>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- rename -->
    <xsl:template match="e">
      <se>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </se>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- discard -->
    <xsl:template match="e[.='DB1']|error"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't deal with namespaces so I removed `xmlns` namespace from the input and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for he quick response.I know basic knowledge on XSLT and wrote one XSLT transformation.But not able to traverse to child element.If i used to xmlns in the XML.

Comment: in the below XSLT am not able get the element node of <e>.I tried so many scenarios to get the child element but couldn't able to find that.

Comment: Without the Namespace.I am able to do it somehow.But with namespace bit difficlut for me to do it.

Comment: I have shared my XSLT below..by using that am able to delete the namespace.but not able to get the child element by using that XSLT.Any idea plz

Answer (score 0):

I have written XSLT tranformation like this..

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="d" >
    <Payload xmlns="http://example.com/test/2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
      <response>
        <allot>8</allot>
        <size>200</size>
        <ses>
          <xsl:for-each select="e">
            <xsl:variable name="e_name" select="."></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$e_name != 'DB1'">
              <se>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
              </se>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ses>
      </response>
    </Payload>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: without xmlns in <Payload> .It is populate XML.But am  facing some issue in XSLT.That is am not able to get child element with my XSLT.

Comment: With myXSLT using that am able to delete the namespace.but not able to get the child element by using that XSLT.Any idea plz